# property initializers run before 'self' is available . How to solve this?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Part of my Code which is inside the class fetchData()

```
 @Published var deviceNmae : String = ""
 @Published  var deviceID : String = ""
    
    init(){
        self.deviceID = "t1199"
    }
    
    let urlString = "https://io.adafruit.com/\(deviceID)/"
```

error i am getting is

```
Cannot use instance member 'deviceID' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available
```

How can i solve this ? i looked into similar questions in stackOverflow but nothing seems to be working can someOne guide me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options:

1. Use a lazy var:

```swift
lazy var urlString = "https://io.adafruit.com/\(deviceID)/"
```

2. Use a computed property

```swift
var urlString: String { "https://io.adafruit.com/\(deviceID)/" }
```

Comment: it's showing Ambiguous use of 'init' for 2nd option

Comment: first option is working